# HTML tag is not 100% width under 576px

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm struggling with a problem that I never faced before. I've been searching for help in internet (mainly here, at SO, but to no avail, becase no one seems to have faced this issue).

I'm developing a site with Bootstrap 4. I'm no new neither to Bootstrap nor to HTML & CSS. I started with the desktop size (I know, "mobile-first", but that's not the point). The thing is that I got to the point of adding responsiveness and got to the mobile size. When I the viewport is under 576px, `.container` gets `width: 100%`, which is the usual behaviour. But to my surprise, I realized that **even being `width: 100%` (I can see it inspectioning) my content expands horizontally just to a 50% (aprox., it depends on resizing) to the viewport**. Testing things and more things, I got to the conclsion that **is `<html>` itself (at the top of everything) which is not taking the 100% of the viewport**.
[image: You can see the problem in this picture]

I even tried going back with Git to previous and early branches in order to isolate the problem, but the problem was already there.

I don't see a reason for this behaviour. I tried everything but to no avail. Maybe it's the simpliest and silliest thing, but I'm desperate. Can anybody help, please? Thanx in advance!

Comment: I'm guessing there is one or multiple element that is overflowing the total html container. Try using the inspect tool of the browser.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul thanx, but I'not sure I understand you. Can you elaborate, please? I did use the inspector tool of the browser, as I stated in my question, it's the 1st thing I always do.

Comment: so did you try settin the width of the html tag to 100vw ? please host your website on glitch or stackblitz or codesandbox so i can debug your site :)  https://codesandbox.io/  https://glitch.com/  https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @DolevDublon I did what you suggested: https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-pine-o5doo and the funny thing is that there at CodeSandbox it's working just fine (it's obviously missing the img files, but the point is the grid). I don't get it. I tried different browsers locally, but the output was the same.

Comment: And yes, @DolevDublon, I tried setting 'html' and 'body' to 100% width, and they are (or at least, inspector says so, but the result is what you see in the picture. It's like somehow 100% width is not equal to 100% of the viewport at mobile size. I also tried '100vw', but with no effect.

Comment: the problem is that i cant re-generate your bug ,  maybe try to also upload the pictures you are using to codeSandbox and then display them ,  so we will be able to help you out ! :) stay motivated !

Comment: if you want contact me on gmail dolev146@gmail.com and i will help u out on zoom call

Comment: @JuanManuelLinares can you provide your website link? I'm guessing (again) that the images ***might*** be a problem.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul thanxs fo your help. I finally found the bug. As you suggested, there were images that were overflowing the container. That's why at CodeSandbox, without images, everything was fine. Thanx to Dolev Deblon too :)